# Getting parent information from child node in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I currently have some xml along the lines of:

```
<Schools>
    <School SchoolName="name1" ... >
        <Students> 
            <Student studentName="student1" .../>
            <Student studentName="student2" .../>
        </Stuidents>
    </School>
    <School SchoolName="name2" ...>
        <Students>
            <Student studentName="student3" ... />
            <Student studentName="student3" ... />
        </Students>
    </School>
</Schools>
```

If I make a node list of "School" and "Student" using a DOM parser, within the Student node list how am I able to get SchoolName from the student so that I am able to save in a Database/Student Class : StudentName, Student Details, SchoolName.

```
NodeList schoolNodeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("School");
NodeList studentNodeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Student");

parseStudentNodeList(studentNodeList);

private void parseStudentNodeList(NodeList studentsNodeList)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    for (int i = 0; i < studentNodeList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Element el (Element) studentNodeList.item(i);
        student.setName(el.getAttribute("studentName"));
        student.setSchool( /* Help needed here */ );
    }
}
```

Preferably by not adding a "SchoolName" variable into the Student section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node has method [getParentNode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getParentNode%28%29), you could get node's parent node.

Comment: Would i not need to use getParentNode().getParentNode() as the Parent of Student is Students and I need School?

Comment: I think so:). Two times getParentNode() :)